flutter while running app gives error on android
E/AndroidRuntime(27978): App is using cpu architecture: armv7l, and the native libraries directory (with path /data/app/promedia.nicekuwaity-mY9ny4y8V5gGxMZFAv7VLg==/lib/arm) contains the following files: [libffmpegkit_armv7a_neon.so, libavfilter_neon.so, libswscale_neon.so, libavdevice_neon.so, libavutil_neon.so, libavcodec_neon.so, libffmpegkit_abidetect.so, libavformat_neon.so, libswresample_neon.so]
E/AndroidRuntime(27978):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:377)
E/AndroidRuntime(27978): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Could not load libflutter.so this is possibly because the application is running on an architecture that Flutter Android does not support (e.g. x86) see https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures 

E/AndroidRuntime(27978): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/promedia.nicekuwaity-mY9ny4y8V5gGxMZFAv7VLg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/promedia.nicekuwaity-mY9ny4y8V5gGxMZFAv7VLg==/lib/arm, /data/app/promedia.nicekuwaity-mY9ny4y8V5gGxMZFAv7VLg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

i try add this line
ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" }

Please remove x86 and try https://stackoverflow.com/a/77509703/4373661  or this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596

Try adding "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" only
ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" }

and then do a flutter clean before trying build again.
